# VueSocketIO offer fallback connection url

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vue-socket.io

I am using Vuetify together with Vuex and VueSocketIO for my WebApp and here is an example Part of the code:

```
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
      reconnection: true,
      debug: true,
      connection: SocketIO(`http://${process.env.ip}:4000`),
      vuex: {
        store,
        actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
      },
    }));
```

If I understand it correctly, using Vuex and VueSocketIO together makes it only possible to use one Socket like this at the same time.

In some cases Vue might not be able to connect to the socket specified at `connection`.
I was wondering if there was a possibility to first let Vue try to connect to one socket (also with some number of reconnection attempts) but to switch to another `connection` value and try with that one afterwards as a fallback?

Thank you in advance!

**Final solution**

```
const options = {
  reconnection: true, 
  reconnectionAttempts: 2, 
  reconnectionDelay: 10,
  reconnectionDelayMax: 1,
  timeout: 300,
};

let connection = new SocketIO(`http://${process.env.ip}:4000`, options);
const instance = new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection,
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
  },
  options,
});

const options2 = {
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 4,
};

connection.on('reconnect_failed', () => {
  connection = new SocketIO(`http://${process.env.fallback}:4000`, options2);
  instance.listener.io = connection;
  instance.listener.register();
  Vue.prototype.$socket = connection;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the number of reconnection attempts you can set [reconnectionAttempts](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/HEAD/docs/API.md#manager) option.

Example Code:

```js
const url = `http://${process.env.ip}:4000`
const options = {
  reconnectionAttempts: 3
}

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: new SocketIO(url, options),
  vuex: { ... }
}))
```

But switching to another connection is not easy as both of `vue-socket.io` and `socket.io-client` it was not designed for that.

- First we have to listen on [reconnect_failed](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/HEAD/docs/API.md#event-reconnect_failed) event which will fires when reconnection attempts is exceeded.
- Then we have to create a new connection to connect to the fallback url.
- The `VueSocketIO` instance have two important properties which `emitter` and `listener` we cannot create the new `emitter` since it might already used in some components (with subscribe function) so we have to use old emitter but new listener.
- Unfortunately, we cannot import `Listener` class directly from `vue-socket.io` package. So we have to use old listener but change the `io` property to the new connection then manually call `register` method.
- Binding `Vue.prototype.$socket` to the new connection for the future use.

Example Code:

```js
const url = `http://${process.env.ip}:4000`
const fallbackUrl = `http://${process.env.ip}:4001`
const options = {
  reconnectionAttempts: 3
}

const connection = new SocketIO(url, options)
const instance = new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection,
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
  },
  options
})

connection.on('reconnect_failed', error => {
  const connection = new SocketIO(fallbackUrl, options)
  instance.listener.io = connection
  instance.listener.register()
  Vue.prototype.$socket = connection;
})

Vue.use(instance)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation! I would have never thought about this solution, especially with us not being able to change the emitter but only to change the io value. I made some first tests and this approach seems to work like a charme!

Comment: I realized it takes a lot of time until the switch of websocket connection happens if the first ip is not reachable. Is this probably related to this code or something different?

Comment: It will take about ~ `reconnectionAttempts` * `reconnectionDelay`. You can set `reconnectionDelayMax`.

Comment: So I tried some rather extreme values (`reconnectionAttempts` to 1 and the `reconenctionDelayMax` to 1) but this did not change anything about how long I need to wait (about 30-40 sec). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think `timeout` is also important here if your server is not responding. The default `timeout` is 20 seconds.

Comment: Ah now I got it to work like intended! Thank you so much, you helped me a lot with my problem. (also I will add my final solution to my original question, for anybody who is interested)